# Is ~/.profile sourced by bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a global counter variable to see how many times `~/.profile` gets executed. Thus:
In `~/.bashrc`:

```
# ... 
if [ "$PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES" = "" ]; then
 export PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES=0
fi
let "PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES += 1"
```

In `~/.profile`:

```
# ... 
export PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES
let "PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES += 1"
```

But when I open a new shell and write `echo $PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES`, all I get is `1`.  `$PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES` must be at least 2. [I suspect](http://speeves.erikin.com/2008/05/bash-export-environment-variable-to.html) that `~/.profile` isn't sourced by bash... if so, what I need to do in order to check how many times `~/.profile` is executed?

---

**Edit:**
I've noticed that `/etc/gdm/Xsession` is sourcing `~/.profile` by the following line:

```
test -f "$HOME/.profile" && . "$HOME/.profile"
```

and `~/.bashrc` is sourced in `~/.profile` by the following lines:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Also, I've add the following line to `~/.bashrc` & `~/.profile`:

```
echo $(cd ${0%/*} && echo $PWD/${0##*/}) >> /home/myUserName/a
```

and could see that only one line was added to the file after I logged in to my user.

I want to emphasize that my goal here is:
**Finding out how many times `~/.profile` is executed when user logs in.**

Additional details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux my-desktop 2.6.32-25-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 19:52:42 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS"
```

- My [/etc/gdm/Xsession](http://pastebin.ca/1990893)
- My [~/.bashrc](http://pastebin.ca/1990894)
- My [~/.profile](http://pastebin.ca/1990895)

Comment: It should only execute once per login. And using an environment variable is not a reliable way to count it. Environment variables are *inherited* by processes forked from the process that adds them. They will not automatically be available to all processes on the system. Use a file to keep count instead. E.g.: `date >> /tmp/profile_runs`. Then you can count the number of lines that has bee appended. `wc -l < /tmp/profile_runs`.

Answer (score 6):

From your comments on my original answer, it appears that your real question is "Is ~/.profile sourced by GNOME?" The answer is yes. Look in `/etc/gdm/Xsession`:

```
# First read /etc/profile and .profile
test -f /etc/profile && . /etc/profile
test -f "$HOME/.profile" && . "$HOME/.profile"
# Second read /etc/xprofile and .xprofile for X specific setup
test -f /etc/xprofile && . /etc/xprofile
test -f "$HOME/.xprofile" && . "$HOME/.xprofile"
```

---

### Original Answer

From the manpage of bash:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login
>   option, it first
>   reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that
>   file exists.  After reading that file,
>   it looks for
>   `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and
>   reads and executes commands from the 
>   first  one
>   that  exists  and is readable.

So you may have a file called .bash_profile or .bash_login in your home directory. If either of these exists, bash will use it instead of .profile.

Comment: Sorry but the info you supplied doesn't help.

Comment: Are you sure that you are invoking bash as an interactive *login* shell? You should edit your question to explain how you are invoking bash.

Comment: I'm not invoking bash, it is automatically invoked by some startup script of my Ubuntu 10.04 desktop, when I login to my user.

Comment: What kind of login? Are you logging into a Terminal? Into GNOME? Into KDE? Into some other desktop?

Comment: When I logging into GNOME.

Comment: So the real question is, does GNOME read `~/.profile` when you log in? The answer should be yes. Look in `/etc/gdm/Xsession`.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to watch what's going on in a shell script, put `set -x` at the top (just after the `#!` line if any). This prints a trace of the execution on standard error. Here the shell's standard error should be redirected to `~/.xsession-errors`.

There's a contradition in your question: you say your goal is “finding out how many times ~/.profile is executed when user logs in”, and then you go on to hack with `.bashrc`. Merely putting `export PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES; let "PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES += 1"` in your `.profile` does count how many times it's sourced, and it's unsurprising that the result is 1 (you only log in once).

Your `.profile` sources `.bashrc`, which is weird as `.profile` is used when logging in and `.bashrc` is the configuration file of bash when it's interactive. Maybe you did this to work around a design bug in bash, whereby it doesn't read `.bashrc` in a shell that is both a login shell and interactive; I prefer to have a `.bash_profile` that sources both `.profile` and (if the shell is interactive) `.bashrc`.

Note that your `.profile` takes care not to source `.bashrc` if the shell isn't bash. This explains why `.bashrc` isn't read when you log in: `/etc/gdm/Xsession` is executed by `/bin/sh`, which on Ubuntu 10.04 is [dash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dash.1.html), not bash.

Near the top of `.bashrc`, you have: “If not running interactively, don't do anything” commenting the line `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. Actually, that line won't do this; it's fairly common for `PS1` to be set in non-interactive shells (for example, it's set by `/etc/profile`). A reliable test for an interactive bash is `[[ $- = *i* ]]`.

You may also be interested in [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile).

Comment: (#1) I think that there's no contradiction, since bash (or the startup script) has many tricky peculiarities that may causing the problem.
(#2) When adding the snippet that increment $PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES to `.bashrc` (and NOT to `.profile`), I still get `1` when echo'ing that variable via a new terminal.
(#3) I didn't intentionally sourced `.profile` from `.bash`. I didn't change anything in `.bashrc` nor in `.profile`, except for the snippet that increments `$PROFILE_EXEC_TIMES`.

Comment: @Dor: The contradiction is between what you claim you want to find out (“finding out how many times ~/.profile is executed when user logs in”) and your next sentence where you mention modifying `~/.bashrc`. Why not put *different* traces in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` if you want to understand what's going on? Add a time to the traces (`date >>/tmp/${0##*/}.log`) and wait a second between logging in and starting a terminal to distinguish between what happens when you log in and what happens when you start a terminal.

Comment: @Dor: Regarding #3, I know the oddities such as sourcing `.bashrc` from `.profile` or the flawed test for an interactive shell aren't from you; they're not even from Ubuntu as they're also in Debian. But if you want to understand what's going on, these are things you need to know.

Comment: I've add the code that you wrote to both `.bashrc` & `.profile` and the result is one file called `Xsession.log` with the following single line: `Sun Nov 21 21:12:45 IST 2010`

Comment: @Dor: Sounds right: `/etc/gdm/Xsession` sources `~/.profile`. I've lost track: is there still something you don't understand?

Comment: Yes. When I append the code to *one* of the files & log into GNOME, there's a single line in the file `Xsession.log`. When I append the code to both files & log into GNOME, there's **still** a single line in the file `Xsession.log` (the file `Xsession.log` is empty before each logon). Why's that? There should be at least two lines in the latter case.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of both files. This will show a trace of their execution on standard error. Standard error should be redirected to `~/.xsession-errors` at this point.

Answer (score 2):

@Dor: I dont have enough reputation yet to write comments, but i can answer you last comment from Dec 7 '10 at 12:41, which was:

*"When I append the code to both files & log into GNOME, there's still a single line in the file Xsession.log (the file Xsession.log is empty before each logon). Why's that? There should be at least two lines in the latter case."*

No, because when you logon in Gnome (using GDM), `~/.bashrc` is NOT executed, only `~/.profile`. As explained by Gilles, Gnome calls `/etc/gdm/Xsession`, which in turn sources `~/.profile`. And `~/.profile` ONLY sources `~/.bashrc` ***if running bash***.

From `~/.profile`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

And when you login in Gnome/GDM, you are **not** using Bash, because, as Gilles also pointed out,  `/etc/gdm/Xsession` has uses the directive `#! /bin/sh`, which in Ubuntu is a symlink to **dash**, not bash.

So the whole Gnome login process does not invoke bash. That why files like /etc/profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.bash_profile are not automatically called. Thats why `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` had to be "manually", explicitly sourced by `/etc/gdm/Xsession`. **And they both test for Bash before sourcing `~/.bashrc`**

The test on "is interactive shell" in /etc/profile (and also on ~/.bashrc) may be flawed, *but the bash test works*, and it return **false** when logging in. Thats why your log file has only 1 line... thats from `~/.profile`

When you open a terminal, its a bash terminal. Bash itself calls `~/.bashrc` directly, and `~/.profile` is not executed.

I hope now everything has cleared up.

Last but not least: **Do not source ~/.profile from ~/.bashrc**, as suggested by previous answer. That will cause a circular reference (both files source each other), and is both technically and conceptualy wrong. It may cause problemns if bash is ever used for login (maybe text mode, repair console?)

Answer (score 0):

`~/.profile` is only executed for login shells (`bash --login`), not all shells, thats what `~/.bashrc` is for. So the count of 1 should be correct, as `~/.profile` is executed once when you login.

If you don't trust the environment variable counter just write a file with a unique filename (something like `$(uuidgen)`) to keep track of the `~/.profile` executions.

Comment: But please do notice that I incremented the counter in both files. So when `~/.bashrc` is executed, the counter equals 1, afterwards `~/.profile` is executed, thus the counter equals 2 (at least).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sourcing .profile in .bashrc? If not, Bash won't read it. You should have something like this, probably best placed at the top of your .bashrc:

```
[ -r ${HOME}/.profile ] && . ${HOME}/.profile
```

That will make sure that .profile both exists and is readable, and if it is than process it.

Comment: I have the following line in `/etc/gdm/Xsession`: `test -f "$HOME/.profile" && . "$HOME/.profile"`. See my edit please.

Comment: No, do not source `.profile` from `.bashrc`. The other way around is ok, and common. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles