# Is ~/.profile effectively sourced on non-login shells?

Tags: bash, startup, .profile

I see that the path variable is defined in my .profile file, and not in my .bashrc file. I have not changed either file. When using a shell initiated from the terminal icon on my desktop GUI, I can still echo $PATH.

So, what I am asking is, is the reason I can do this because, when I clicked the icon on my desktop for the terminal, a login shell process forked to the non-login shell I am interacting with, so the non-login shell I am using inherited the environment of the login shell, which was sourced from .profile? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13077/is-profile-sourced-by-bash -- your ~/.profile might be sourced when you log in to the GUI desktop

Comment: Also check the settings of your terminal: is it configured to launch a login shell?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is a simple "yes", assuming that .profile exports PATH.

Comment: @glennjackman where is the best place to confirm if the terminal is configured to launch a login shell?

Comment: With the Gnome terminal: Edit -> Preferences; select a profile; Command tab; checkbox labelled "Run command as a login shell"